# search list of tuples and exchange tup[0] for tup[2] in another list

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

```
x =  [(u'red', 3.5, u'rouge'), (u'green', 2.6, u'vert'), (u'blue', 1.45, u'blu')]

y = [('bue', 14.5), ('red', 140.0), ('green', 130.0), ('', 0.0)]
```

I want to search x for y[0] and change x[0] to y[0] if it's found.

I have been getting TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple when I try to loop through the tuple.

Sorry for my explanation I will try again.

```
x = [('a', 'b','c'),('d','e','f'),('g','h','i')]
y = [('zzz',10), ('xxx',20), ('yyy',30)]
```

I want to end up with a list that is `y =[('c', 10),('f',20),('i',30)]`

I have tried numerous things but I am new to python and have tried the following

```
for tup  in x:
      results = [(tup[2]) for tup in x]

for tup in x:
    if tup[0] == y[tup[0]]:
        y[tup[0]] = tup[2]
```

Comment: what you have tried, show code??

Comment: Let's see your code.

Comment: a trivial `d = {i[0]: i[2] for i in x}` and then `[(d.get(i[0], i[0]), i[1]) for i in y]` should do?

Answer (score 1):

This is a literal interpretation of your question, if `y[0][0]` which is `'blue'` is in any tuple in x, swap that tuple for `y[0]` which is I presume suppose to be contain `blue` not `bue`  so `x[2]` becomes `y[0]`:

```
x = [(u'red', 3.5, u'rouge'), (u'green', 2.6, u'vert'), (u'blue', 1.45, u'blu')]

y = [('blue', 14.5), ('red', 140.0), ('green', 130.0), ('', 0.0)]

for ind, tup in enumerate(x):
    if y[0][0] in tup:
        x[ind] = y[0]
print(x)
[(u'red', 3.5, u'rouge'), (u'green', 2.6, u'vert'), ('blue', 14.5)]
```

Or using a list comprehension and creating a new list:

```
print([y[0]  if tup[0] == y[0][0] else tup for tup in x])
[(u'red', 3.5, u'rouge'), (u'green', 2.6, u'vert'), ('blue', 14.5)]
```

To just swap elements:

```
x = [('a', 'b','c'),('d','e','f'),('g','h','i')]
y = [('zzz',10), ('xxx',20), ('yyy',30)]


for ind,ele in enumerate(x):
    y[ind] = (ele[-1],y[ind][1])
print(y)
[('c', 10), ('f', 20), ('i', 30)]
```

Comment: I have tried those and it doesn't do what I want perhaps I explained  it wrong in my naivety.

Comment: x = [('a', 'b','c'),('d','e','f'),('g','h','i')]
y = [('zzz',10), ('xxx',20), ('yyy',30)]   I want to end up with a list that equals  result = [('c', 10), ('f',20),('i',30)]

Comment: add what your expected output is

Comment: y =[('c', 10),('f',20),('i',30)]

Comment: You are a star! I appreciate immensely.